# Is there any way using multiple single C-style comments to block comment C language in VSCode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have read the document of VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> does:

```c
// int main() {
//   return 0;
// }
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> does:

```c
/* int main() {
  return 0;
} */
```

But I want something like Emacs way:

```c
/* int main() { */
/*   return 0; */
/* } */
```

How can I switch or customize the style inner VSCode itself?

Comment: Maybe in keyboard settings you can find something that helps you, for that press ctrl + shift + p and the terminal opens, then type keyboard and see what options you have there.

Comment: Short of writing your own plug-in you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your own macro to do this.  Using the macro extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) put these into your `keybindings.json` file:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+A",     // whatever keybinding you like
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": {
      "sequence": [
        "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",
        "cursorLineStartSelect",
        "editor.action.blockComment"
      ]
    },
    "when": "editorFocus && editorHasSelection"  // with a selection
  },

{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+A",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "cursorEnd",
      "cursorLineStartSelect",
      "editor.action.blockComment"
    ]
  },
  "when": "editorFocus && !editorHasSelection"  // no selection
}
```

The first keybinding triggers when you have selected text.  It will add a cursor to the end of each line within the selection, then select the entire line and blockComment it to get your desired effect.

The second keybinding works when there is no selection, like if you just had a single line you wanted to blockComment.  It also works with multiple cursors.  The cursor(s) can be anywhere on the line and the whole line will be blockCommented.

[image: block comment each line demo]

---

[If these don't act exactly the way you want, just let me know and they can be tweaked.]

Comment: Wow! It's wonderful and workable. Thanks to your hard work. But there are some little problems can be improved: 1. It comment out empty lines. This is unexpected. 2. It comment start at line head, not start at statement head. 3. Without select a whole line, I think it should start comment at the tail. Anyway, you have done a good job. And I think I should develop it by myself.

Comment: If you select empty lines they will be commented - no way to prevent that.  #2 can probably be fixed - you mean comment at start of code?  #3 If you select part of a line you want the comment at the end?

Comment: #2 Right, I mean comment start at the code head. So as what we use in Emacs. #3 I want use only one key to do any comment. Start comment at the tail when I have not selected any part of code.

Comment: #2 you could use `cursorHomeSelect` instead of `cursorLineStartSelect`, but the comment characters will not line up nicely on indented code.  Only writing an extension could fix that or #1.  #3 I think just remove the `cursorLineStartSelect` from the `!editorHasSelection` version.  [I can't test these right now unfortunately.]  It'll go to the end of the line and insert a blockComment.